# Handling occasional undefined errors nicely in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If at any point, I get an error, by trying to do something with an undefined, my entire express app crashes with a TypeError, instead of handling it nicely by redirecting to an HTTP 500 page.

Is there any way to handle these exceptions generally, or I will need to manually check in my router methods?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this from the [**docs - Express Error handling**](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)?

> Error-handling middleware are defined just like regular middleware, however must be defined with an arity of 4, that is the signature (err, req, res, next):
>
> ```
> app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
>    console.error(err.stack);
>    res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
> });
> ```
>
> Though not mandatory error-handling middleware are typically defined very last...

Comment: yes, I know about the way express handles errors ... yet, I will still need to manually check whether a particular variable in ma method is undefined, and then pass an error with the "next()" handler, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `try { ... } catch(e) {...}` is what you are looking for?
Or just checks if value is not undefined. Simple `if (value) { ...` will do the job

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by phenomenal you can use express error handler middle-ware to handle error at centralized place.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
console.error(err.stack);
res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
```

Than to pass error from your routes you can use next to pass error to this middle-ware like this

```
app.get('/login',function(req,res,next){
next("your error"); // The error middle-ware handle this error.
})
```